# Proving Properties Of Continuous Functions

Tags: calculus

Suppose there is a function $f(x)$ continuous on the interval $[a, b]$, then there exists some $u, v$ in the interval $[a, b]$ such that $$f(u) \leq f(x) \leq f(v)$$ for all $x$ in the interval $[a, b]$.
$$$$Suppose that the above fact is not true, then we have for every $t$ there is some $x$ in the interval $[a, b]$ such that $$f(x)>f(t)$$. Now Chose $c_1$ then there exists a $c_2$ such that $$f(c_2)>f(c_1)$$, also for $c_2$ there exists a $c_3$ such that $$f(c_3)>f(c_2)$$. Now consider this sequence $c_n$ as this sequence is bounded as $a \leq c_n \leq b$ for every $n$ so there is a subsequence $c_{n_j}$ which converges to some point say $c$, then as $f(x)$ is a continuous function so as $c_{n_j}$ converges to $c$ $f(c_{n_j})$ converges to $f(c)$. Now consider the sequence $p_n=f(c_n)$, it is easy to see that this is an increasing sequence and as the function is continuous on the interval $[a, b]$ so it is bounded also and hence this sequence $p_n$ converges to its least Upper Bound say $L$ but it's subsequence $p_{n_j}=f(c_{n_j})$ converges to $f(c)$ and hence $L=f(c)$ but according to our assumption for this $c$ again there exists some $c_k$ such that $f(c_k)>f(c)$ but as $L=f(c)$ is the least Upper Bound for $f(c_n)$, so we arrive at an contradiction. So there exists some $t$ such that $$f(x) \leq f(t)$$ for all $x$ in the interval $[a, b]$. Similarly we can prove that there is some $t'$ such that $$f(x) \geq f(t')$$ for all $x$ in the interval $[a, b]$.
$$$$Is The Above Proof Correct??

Comment: $f(x)$ is not strictly increasing here

Comment: What are you saying plz clarify??

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question

Comment: Oh but can you plz tell wether the proof is correct or not?

Comment: @David Peterson Hey What happened??